Arjuna, indicating that an action completed with multiple threads, and one of the threads was in progress
I have this application where with applyAsync method I get data from other service then try to save in our database ,this process can be done at the same time I mean i request data it starts working in the background and i do again with other parameters then it works for those parameters.
  @Override
    public CompletableFuture<String> initiateJob(String derivativeType, String minDate, String maxDate) {
        String jobId = jobService.generateJobDerivativeId(derivativeType, minDate, maxDate);
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            executeJob(jobId, derivativeType);
            return jobId;
        });
    }

 @Transactional
    void executeJob(String jobId, String derivativeType) {

        // Since the overall process occurs within a single transaction, the job creation doesn't happen immediately when the user clicks.
        // Consequently, if the user clicks again immediately, the job might not yet exist, thus avoiding potential duplication.
        // To address this, job creation is performed within a new transaction (REQUIRES_NEW).
        // However, when setting the PsbomResponse for association later, the job entity is already detached.
        // Therefore, we retrieve the job from the database to reattach it to the current transaction context before establishing the association. > here

        JobPSBOMEntity job = jobService.createJob(jobId, derivativeType);
        try {

            LOG.info("Job is created with id: " + job.getId());
            //in case error throws in catch it handles with changing job status to FAILED

            ResponseDTO responseDTO = remoteService.sendProxyPostRequest(derivativeType);

  @Override
    public ResponseDTO sendProxyPostRequest(String derivativeType) {
        Client client;
        // Create the client instance
        client = remoteServiceClientProvider.createClientWithDisabledSSL();
        // Use the client for remote service communication

//        Client client = remoteServiceClientProvider.createClientWithDisabledSSL();
        String authHeader = Base64Encoder.getEncodedBasicAuth(username, password);
        String dataVersion = "";
        String cursor = "";
        ResponseDTO responseDTO;
        int rows = 10000;
        Set<PartUsageDTO> partUsageDTOSet = new HashSet<>();
        Set<MaterialVersionDTO> materialVersionDTOS = new HashSet<>();
        Set<MoboRuleDTO> moboRuleDTOS = new HashSet<>();
        do {

            LOG.info("CURRENT ONE IS: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

            String requestBody = TestData.getBody(dataVersion, cursor, derivativeType, rows);

            // Make the HTTP POST request
            Response response = client.target(url)
                    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader)
                    .post(Entity.json(requestBody));

            responseDTO = response.readEntity(ResponseDTO.class);
            response.close();


            LOG.info("SIZE BEFORE INSERT PARTUSAGE: " + partUsageDTOSet.size());
            LOG.info("SIZE BEFORE INSERT materialVersionDTOS: " + materialVersionDTOS.size());
            LOG.info("SIZE BEFORE INSERT moboRuleDTOS: " + moboRuleDTOS.size());

            partUsageDTOSet.addAll(responseDTO.partUsages());
            if (responseDTO.referencedEntities() != null) {
                materialVersionDTOS.addAll(responseDTO.referencedEntities().materialVersions());

            }
            if (responseDTO.referencedEntities() != null && responseDTO.referencedEntities().moboRules() != null && !responseDTO.referencedEntities().moboRules().isEmpty()) {
                moboRuleDTOS.addAll(responseDTO.referencedEntities().moboRules());
            }

            LOG.info("SIZE AFTER INSERT PARTUSAGE: " + partUsageDTOSet.size());
            LOG.info("SIZE AFTER INSERT materialVersionDTOS: " + materialVersionDTOS.size());
            LOG.info("SIZE AFTER INSERT moboRuleDTOS: " + moboRuleDTOS.size());

            // Extract dataVersion and cursor from the response
            dataVersion = responseDTO.metadata().dataVersion();
            cursor = responseDTO.metadata().nextPageCursor();
        } while (cursor != null && !cursor.isEmpty());
        LOG.info("Number of requests made*****************: ");


        List<MaterialVersionDTO> materialVersionDTOArrayList = new ArrayList<>(materialVersionDTOS);
        List<MoboRuleDTO> moboRuleDTOArrayList = new ArrayList<>(moboRuleDTOS);
        List<PartUsageDTO> partUsageDTOArrayList = new ArrayList<>(partUsageDTOSet);

        ReferencedEntitiesDTO referencedEntitiesDTO = new ReferencedEntitiesDTO(materialVersionDTOArrayList, moboRuleDTOArrayList);

        return new ResponseDTO(new MetadataDTO("", ""), partUsageDTOArrayList, referencedEntitiesDTO);
    }

@Singleton
public class RemoteServiceClientProvider {

    public Client createClientWithDisabledSSL() {
        try {
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return null;
                        }

                        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        }

                        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        }
                    }
            };

            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

            HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = (hostname, session) -> true;

            return jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                    .sslContext(sslContext)
                    .hostnameVerifier(allHostsValid)
                    .build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create a client with disabled SSL validation", e);
        }
    }

I'm trying to make it work with one request it seems okay i think but at the same time i get warn then at the end of first process in DB there's in row inserted.
this is the exception
{"timestamp":"10:59:36.108","sequence":4484,"loggerClassName":"com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjunaI18NLogger_$logger","loggerName":"com.arjuna.ats.arjuna","level":"INFO","message":"ARJUNA012404: Action id 0:ffffc0a86506:ff77:6658238e:7 - thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-14 at time 10:59:36.107 had stackTrace java.base@17.0.7/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)\njava.base@17.0.7/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:47)\njava.base@17.0.7/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.tryRead(NioSocketImpl.java:261)\njava.base@17.0.7/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:312)\njava.base@17.0.7/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)\njava.base@17.0.7/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)\njava.base@17.0.7/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)\njava.base@17.0.7/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:484)\njava.base@17.0.7/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readFully(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:467)\njava.base@17.0.7/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decodeInputRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:243)\njava.base@17.0.7/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:181)\njava.base@17.0.7/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)\njava.base@17.0.7/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1509)\njava.base@17.0.7/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1480)\njava.base@17.0.7/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1065)\norg.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)\norg.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)\norg.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)\norg.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.getChunkSize(ChunkedInputStream.java:261)\norg.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(ChunkedInputStream.java:222)\norg.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:183)\norg.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:135)\njava.base@17.0.7/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:132)\norg.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.AbstractBuiltResponse$InputStreamWrapper.read(AbstractBuiltResponse.java:543)\ncom.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._loadMore(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:264)\ncom.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._skipWS2(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3073)\ncom.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._skipWS(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3068)\ncom.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:784)\ncom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:424)\ncom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1493)\ncom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:348)\ncom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:185)\ncom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:359)\ncom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:244)\ncom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:28)\ncom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:545)\ncom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeWithErrorWrapping(BeanDeserializer.java:570)\ncom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:440)\ncom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1493)\ncom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:348)\ncom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:185)\ncom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:342)\ncom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:2099)\ncom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1249)\norg.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider.readFrom(ResteasyJackson2Provider.java:184)\norg.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:99)\norg.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:81)\norg.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.readFrom(ClientResponse.java:192)\norg.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.readEntity(BuiltResponse.java:75)\norg.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.AbstractBuiltResponse.readEntity(AbstractBuiltResponse.java:232)\ncom.bmw.madam.service.RemoteServiceImpl.sendProxyPostRequest(RemoteServiceImpl.java:75)\ncom.bmw.madam.service.RemoteServiceImpl_ClientProxy.sendProxyPostRequest(Unknown Source)\ncom.bmw.madam.service.main.PSBOMFacadeServiceImpl.executeJob(PSBOMFacadeServiceImpl.java:70)\ncom.bmw.madam.service.main.PSBOMFacadeServiceImpl_Subclass.executeJob$$superforward(Unknown Source)\ncom.bmw.madam.service.main.PSBOMFacadeServiceImpl_Subclass$$function$$2.apply(Unknown Source)\nio.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:73)\nio.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:62)\nio.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:136)\nio.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:107)\nio.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.doIntercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:38)\nio.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:61)\nio.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:32)\nio.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)\nio.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)\nio.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:30)\nio.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:27)\ncom.bmw.madam.service.main.PSBOMFacadeServiceImpl_Subclass.executeJob(Unknown Source)\ncom.bmw.madam.service.main.PSBOMFacadeServiceImpl.lambda$initiateJob$0(PSBOMFacadeServiceImpl.java:39)\ncom.bmw.madam.service.main.PSBOMFacadeServiceImpl$$Lambda$2320/0x0000000801b4b0c8.get(Unknown Source)\njava.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768)\njava.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1760)\njava.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)\njava.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)\njava.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)\njava.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)\njava.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)\n","threadName":"Transaction Reaper Worker 0","threadId":240,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"laptop0790","processName":"td-madam-psbom-dev.jar","processId":74651} {"timestamp":"10:59:36.147","sequence":4485,"loggerClassName":"com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjunaI18NLogger_$logger","loggerName":"com.arjuna.ats.arjuna","level":"WARN","message":"ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffffc0a86506:ff77:6658238e:7 invoked while multiple threads active within it.","threadName":"Transaction Reaper Worker 0","threadId":240,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"laptop0790","processName":"td-madam-psbom-dev.jar","processId":74651} 

The stacktrace includes "TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:107" according to what I see on the main narayana branch (you didn't say which version of narayana you were using). If this is the correct stack frame then it is saying "Not supported for interception factory with non-weld CDI implementation for bean {0}". But the issue report does not say which bean includes the non-weld CDI annotation. Can you investigate your logs, and your code, to see if you can determine which annotation the log message is referring to.

for now added default transaction timeout and seems to be working

i also have this @Singleton
public class RemoteServiceClientProvider { for client creatiob


io.quarkus
quarkus-narayana-jta
missing this too